# Form: A drawing as a form field

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe

Can I implement the following as a form, to set the cross mark?

[image]

A Form-Document:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half, paper=a4,]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},  germandbls={ß}}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 %   \pagecolor{yellow!40}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print,bordercolor={red},borderstyle=U}

\textbf{Notice:}\\[0.75ex]
\TextField[multiline, name=Notizen,width=0.9\textwidth,  height=3.25cm,borderstyle=D,value={}, backgroundcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95}]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Merry Christmas. Why two documentclass?

Comment: @Sebastiano: The OP posted the same document twice, accidently, most likely... the second `\documentclass` is never seen, since TeX stops after `\end{document}`

Comment: OK, I took liberty to remove the duplicate part of the OP question.

Comment: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/23861/formular-zeichnung-als-formularfeld

Comment: @Johannes_B Click on your link - better?

Comment: I didn't want you to delete the question. But it should be properly linked.

Comment: No one TeXi in Germany does use AdobeReader. It is not  functional to discuss questions about AdobeReader-Functions there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enter integer numbers between `0` and `90`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[nomouse, step, label = picfield]{90}

  \multiframe{90}{iangle=0+1}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % box
    \fill[yellow!20] (0, 0) rectangle (11, 4);

    % description
    \node [below right, text width = 4cm, align = justify] at (0, 4) {\small\textbf{9.4} Use a cross
    on the bow to show how tall the object was when it was seen};

    \begin{scope}[xshift = 5.0cm, yshift = 0.5cm]

      % cloud
      \node[cloud, cloud puffs = 10.3, cloud ignores aspect, minimum width = 1.5cm, minimum height = 0.8cm, align=center, draw, fill = blue!30] (cloud) at (5, 3){};

      % tree
      \fill[brown] (4.9, 0) rectangle (5.1, 1.0);
      \node[cloud, cloud puffs = 11.3, cloud ignores aspect, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm, align=center, draw, fill = green!60!black] (tree) at (5, 0.8){};


      % bow
      \draw[black] (0, 0) -- (3, 0) node[right]{$\ang{0}$} arc (0 : 90: 3)
      node[above]{$\ang{90}$} -- cycle;
      \foreach \x in {0, 5, ..., 90} {
        \draw[black] (\x : 2.9) -- (\x : 3);
      }

      % marker
      \fill[red] (\iangle : 3.0) circle(0.1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }


\end{animateinline}

\TextField[name = angle, width = 0.9\textwidth, height = 20pt, borderstyle = D, value={}, backgroundcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95}]{}
\PushButton[onclick={anim.picfield.frameNum = getField('angle').value;}]{\strut Submit}
\end{center}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am impressed. Someone using animate's JS interface.

Comment: Wow! This is a very   impressively  solution!

Comment: PS: And the tree and the cloud are cool too. :()

Comment: Ouhhh, I have an important question: Is there a possibility to save the Form-PDF with the choosen position?

Comment: @cis do you mean to change the marker and then store the pdf? I'm not sure if the viewer allows you to do that. How about just creating a simple frame with the position you want? It is just a matter of copying everything in the `tikzpicture` environment, and change the value of `iangle` to whatever value you want

Comment: False alarm! I was wondering why no question comes, if I want to save. But if I  type in 33° and save the Form-PDF manually and open it again, the entry and the marking position will remain! Excellent!

Comment: Ah ok, it is saving the value, but not the picture. Whatever... ;)